# How can I change `add_module_names` to `False` for specific modules?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, qualified-name

How can I change `add_module_names` to `False` for specific modules?

I have the following structure:

```py
src/
    / _foo
       some_file.py
    / bar
       some_other_file.py
```

I would like that all functions documents with `.. autofunction::` from the  `_foo` module to have the name of the module hidden, while all functions of the bar module display the name.

Is there a way for me to perform this configuration by module, or even individually for each function?

Comment: What did you try in your .rst? We kind of do this in Pyramid docs. See [HTML](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/authentication.html#pyramid.authentication.extract_http_basic_credentials) and [.rst source](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/_sources/api/authentication.rst.txt) for `extract_http_basic_credentials`. The module name appears as the page title, but can be removed. You need to indent the function name under the module name as in the example.

Comment: @StevePiercy your solution [uses a different value for `add_module_names`](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/1.10-branch/docs/conf.py#L119). The problem with the `True` value is Sphinx will automatically prepend everywhere - and the question is about making an exception in that scenario. I write my `.rst` like you because it allows for finer control of how the names are rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`add_module_names`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-add_module_names) boolean is a general configuration setting in `conf.py`. It reflects your project-wide choice to render module names with objects, it can't be changed for a specific module. An exception to the rule can be implemented but the workaround requires some extra writing.

The solution is to explicitly declare the members you want using a domain directive, in this case [`.. py:function::`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#python-signatures). This lets you specify the signature and the [fully qualified name - PEP 3155](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/). The drawback is you won't be using [an autodoc directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autofunction) so you loose the automatic extraction of docstrings from your Python source code. Depending on where you decide to place `.. py:function::` it may be necessary to use [`:noindex:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#basic-markup) and [`:exclude-members:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_flags) in specific directives - usage shown in the example.

Notice the last example still requires a leading `.` dot, otherwise Sphinx will prepend the fully qualified name as specified by `add_module_names = True`.

Two simple example files, `bar.some_other_file.py`:

```py
"""bar.some_other_file module docstring."""

def some_other_function():
    """some_other_function docstring."""
```

and `_foo.some_file.py`:

```py
"""_foo.some_file module docstring."""

def some_function(argument_example="a string"):
    """some_function docstring."""
```

Using the following `.rst` to compare both cases:

```
_foo costum module name
-----------------------

.. automodule:: _foo.some_file
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :exclude-members: some_function

    .. autofunction:: some_function

    .. py:function:: .some_function(argument_example="a string")
        :noindex:

        Example without any module name.

bar costum module name
----------------------

.. automodule:: bar.some_other_file
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :exclude-members: some_other_function

    .. autofunction:: some_other_function

    .. py:function:: bar.some_other_file.some_function(argument_example="a string")
        :noindex:

        Example with a different qualified name.
```

Gives the following result:

[image]